# external CSS is being stripped on IE when rendered using Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code below that is being rendered on websites via Javascript:

```
<div id="rs_overlay">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="CSS URL HERE">
  <div id="rs_content">

      <div id="rs_images">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="rs_image">
            <img height="161" src="http://www.dwellstudio.com/media/upload/image/35a1zki.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rs_clear">
      <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The overlay layout is working fine on webkit and moz browsers and IE9, however this is failing on IE8 and IE7 because the line

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="CSS URL HERE">
```

is being stripped out on IE7/8.

Any thoughts except for inline css?

Comment: `<link>` may appear only in the `<head>` block, not randomly in the document body. Your html is therefore invalid, and for a change, IE is doing the right thing to ignore it.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with RoR.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B commented, `<link>` tags should be placed in `<head>`.  Your script should create the `<link>` element and append it there.

Example:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
var elem = document.createElement('link');
elem.type = 'text/css';
elem.rel = 'stylesheet';
elem.href = "CSS URL HERE";
head.appendChild(elem);
```